# Orbits in circular path with pure CSS3 not working

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to make an animation of a planet orbiting a little sun. But it is not working properly. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I'll highly appreciate if someone can give me some light. Thanks. here is the CSS code:

```css
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: indigo;
}

.divDePruebas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: inset 36px 0 40px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), inset -10px 0 5px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
  background-image: url(lava.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.8;
  animation: orbit 15s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 310px;
  left: 310px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes orbit {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(150px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sun"></div>
<div class="planet"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I noticed you don't accept any answers given to your questions. You are suppose to do that, and the reason is for other users to see which you picked. This is a way to serve all of us, you included, when one can see a questions accepted answer. Also, not doing that will make some users not pay any interest in your future question. I hope you find this make sense and catch up doing that.

Comment: It is not that I'm a rude person, it is just that I don't know how to accept answers. It may sounds stupid but I'm really new to stackoverflow. Please, tell me how to do it...I've been trying to find a "like" button or something alike, but I really don't know how to accept answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, LGSon,  thanks to it I searched all the screen and found it. Now I'm able to accept answers.

Comment: Good you found it :) ... I also posted an answer explaining what is going on in this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in more than one way, though in this case it is based on the fact that you used `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` in your `.planet` rule, and then when adding the animation, which alter the very same property, it overwrite the existing value.

If you add it back also in the keyframe, like this,

- `transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);`,

it will work as intended

*Also, the `transform` execute the transformation values from right to left, so it start with first doing `translateX(150px)` and so on, hence you need the `translate(-50%, -50%)` as the left most value*

Stack snippet

```css
.sun {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: indigo;
}

.planet {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: inset 36px 0 40px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), inset -10px 0 5px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16);
  background-image: url(lava.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.8;
  animation: orbit 15s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 210px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes orbit {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) translateX(150px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg) translateX(150px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sun"></div>
<div class="planet"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the property transform-origin

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

and btw in your question you used the class divDePruebas in the css and planet in the html

Comment: buxbeatz, thanks for replying, but I added the property transform-origin, and the behavior is still the same. What could it be? The orbiting planet should always keep the same distance from the tiny planet in the center but it moves away and aproaches. Thanks for your time helping me.

Comment: it works fine in my fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/tcmmpyfs/2/ have you added all the vendor prefixes (-moz-, -webkit- ecc?). and btw, the position (top/left) of planet and sun must be the same